# Get query string in Spray routing directive

Tags: scala, spray

I need to set a redirect in my routing directives:

```
path("old") {
  params { p =>
    redirect("http://newu.rl/foo?" + ???, StatusCodes.PermanentRedirect)
  }
}
```

Can I obtain the exact query string sent by the client? Or do I need to reconstruct it from the parameters `p`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom directive using [extract](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/basic-directives/extract/#extract) to retrieve the query string from the uri:

```
val queryString = extract(_.request.uri.query)
path("old") {
  queryString { query =>
    redirect("http://newu.rl/foo?" + query, StatusCodes.PermanentRedirect)
  }
}
```